# CONNECT ERROR: Failed to create directory

Tags: magento-1.9, php, extensions

The mentioned error comes when I try to upload an extension package to my local machine via **System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager > Direct package file upload**.
[image]

I have given `777` access to all the directories of magento installation but it still keep on showing same error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Comment: It is really helpful info but we are building a plugin which will be installed by us on our client's magento installations. We want to make installation easy which can be done by non technical person. FTP upload requires some technical background.